# "field has incomplete type" error during std::unordered_map type object declaration

Tags: c++, class, stl

I'm just trying to create following class:

```
class model
{

  public:

    .
    .
    .
    unordered_map<string, material> materials;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

After commenting this line program compiles succesfully. After uncommenting produces following error:

```
In file included from glmw1.cpp:1:
In file included from ./global.hpp:3:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/stdc++.h:54:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/ccomplex:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/complex:45:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/sstream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/istream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:215:11: error: field has incomplete type 'material'
      _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
.
.
.
```

material is just common class. I have also declared some objects of type "model" in my program (if it makes a difference)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre], which anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as is*** (which can't be done for the shown code), attempt to compile, and get the same error, otherwise nobody will be able to tell you the reason for the error.

Comment: Which part of this code you don't understand? material is whichever class.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and don't use `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the definition of the material object in order to have a collection of them, you cannot just forward declare them. The compiler needs to know how much memory etc to use for them.

Comment: OK. I thought that it was enough to declare a class to be able to do it, and the definition could be anywhere ... After moving the material definition over the model, everything works.